# How to create multiple threads for ServiceStack RabbitMQ consumer?

Tags: multithreading, servicestack, rabbitmq

I need to integrate MQ feature in my ServiceStack application. I have registered the Message Handler in AppHost. The handler for my ServiceStack request(Post) will publish the message to the MQ broker. I have created the consumer for that message. This is all working fine.

Now what I need is to have multiple threads available to consume the message and process that. I have read that ServiceStack implementation of rabbitMQ provides the feature to specify multiple threads for an operation:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#allocating-multiple-threads-for-specific-operations

But I am not able to specify these threads. I have registered the handler as

container.Register(c => new RabbitMqServer());

var mqServer = container.Resolve();

mqServer.RegisterHandler(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads: 4);

But it gives me error as RegisterHandler does not have parameter 'noOfThreads'.
I am running the 4.0.24.0 version for ServiceStack RabbitMQ. Is there something else that I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [noOfThreads is only available on the RabbitMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/63e905a5b82ca99ab57f96107d03cdc9044cf3e0/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqServer.cs#L155) and not a feature of the generic IMessageService. You need to cast the IMessageService you get back from the Container.Resolve() to a RabbitMqServer.

```
container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RabbitMqServer());
var mqServer = (RabbitMqServer)container.Resolve<IMessageService>();
mqServer.RegisterHandler<CallBatchMessage>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads: 4);
```

Comment: Jackson, Thank you so much! Such a fool I am, was trying to cast this other way round and scratching my head all day long.